# Google signout button is not working whenever i press the button it show me an error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

```
2020-04-26 02:18:54.405 8380-8380/com.pk.kasib.karigarapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pk.kasib.karigarapp, PID: 8380
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient is not configured to use Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API required for this call.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkArgument(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaw.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzh.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzf.signOut(Unknown Source)
        at com.pk.kasib.karigarapp.Activities.DriverHome.signOut(DriverHome.java:881)
        at com.pk.kasib.karigarapp.Activities.DriverHome.onNavigationItemSelected(DriverHome.java:576)
```

DriverActiviy Code:

```
private void signOut() {
    if (account != null) {

        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DriverHome.this, MainPageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this, "Could not log out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    } else if (isLoggedInFacebook) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(DriverHome.this, MainPageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(DriverHome.this, MainPageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error looks like configuration not completed: `GoogleApiClient is not configured to use Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API required for this call.` Check the docs to set up correctly.

Comment: I do check it many time but still stuck on it

Comment: I was connecting 2 application with one project
other one is working just fine but this have error

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).